# How to set up ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent, passphrase

I have set up ssh-agent. The problem is, it stills asks for a pass-phrase every time! How do I set it up to only ask for a pass-phrase once? It would be best if it only asked when it was first needed, but if it asks on login, that is okay too.

Comment: Please provide log output and we'll try to help

Answer (score 0):

Just install the *ssh-askpass-gnome* package.

Then add an *ssh-add.desktop* file to *~/.config/autostart* directory, with the following content :

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Exec=/usr/bin/ssh-add
Hidden=false
NoDisplay=false
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=SSH agent passphrase
```